# Why react-router combines previous route with a new one?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, navigation, react-router

Here is my Router.js file

```
// imports here

export default () => (
  <Router>
    <App>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route exact path="/users" component={Users} />
      <Route path="/users/:id" component={User} />
      <Route path="/about" component={About} />
    </App>
  </Router>
);
```

and my App.js file

```
const App = props => (
  <div>
    <nav>
      <Link to="/">Home</Link>
      <Link to={{ pathname: '/users', state: { prevPath: props.location.pathname } }}>Users</Link>
      <Link to="about">About</Link>
    </nav>
    {props.children}
  </div>
);

export default compose(withRouter)(App);
```

When I select '/users' path and then click on any user to navigate to '/users/:id', it works fine and route is http://localhost:3000/users/some-user-id. But when I want to navigate after this route to a route '/about'

url address becomes http://localhost:3000/users/about , instead of http://localhost:3000/about ? What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Use back slash in Link:

```
const App = props => (
  <div>
    <nav>
      <Link to="/">Home</Link>
      <Link to={{ pathname: '/users', state: { prevPath: props.location.pathname } }}>Users</Link>
      <Link to="/about">About</Link>
    </nav>
    {props.children}
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add **exact** in the link to about page

```
    export default () => (
      <Router>
        <App>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route exact path="/users" component={Users} />
          <Route path="/users/:id" component={User} />
          <Route exact path="/about" component={About} />
        </App>
      </Router>
    );
```

And add a backslash in App.js and destructure the props

```
const App = ({children, location}) => (
  <div>
    <nav>
      <Link to="/">Home</Link>
      <Link to={{ pathname: '/users', state: { prevPath: location.pathname } }}>Users</Link>
      <Link to="/about">About</Link>
    </nav>

    {children}
  </div>
);

export default compose(withRouter)(App);
```